# 2 virtual env + celery + supervisor unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file

Tags: django, celery, supervisord

I'm using redis as the backend and I have 2 virtual env each with it's own celery workers.

I'm having a weird issue when I'm adding the celery supervisord conf of the second virtual env.

This is the error I'm getting after reloading supervisord:

```
unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file
```

This is the supervisord conf file:

```html
[program:shopify-celery]
command=dir/bin/celery worker --app=app -l warning -Q queue -n worker -P eventlet -c 3
directory=/dir
user=user
group=webapps
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/dir/logs/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/dir/logs/celery-worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600pip freez

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
;killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
;priority=998
```

I couldn't find what might caused this.

Do you know what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggling with this it turned out that a missing log file did all of this.
I created the needed log file and things work perfectly now.

May be this will help someone else.